# Help identifying a horror illustration

Tags: vampire, object-identification, art

I've had a particular color illustration or painting in my mind, and despite it having very distinct elements for searching online, I just can't find it or the artist. I remember it from a horror graphic arts book from when I was a kid in the 1970's (could easily be from the 1960's, but the style makes me think it could not have been much older than that). I believe this piece was on the cover of a book of horror art (I saw that at a book fair). But that was different from the book I had in the 1970's, which had other art by the same artist - different themes but all horror and supernatural. I can' think of another example, but I remember the art was in a very distinctive style.

Here are my recollections: the scene was in the daytime, in a field (rolling hills), like a cattle pasture, with a short wooden fence in the foreground. There are several decapitated heads along the fence and fence posts. The heads all have anguished expressions, and blood dripping onto the fence. There is a male vampire drinking blood from one of the heads, and he is holding an axe with blood on the blade. His expression is sinister, and he is looking straight out at the viewer of the artwork. It was NOT in comic-book style.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? I've been looking for this for a long time - would like to know the artist and name of the piece if possible (or even a link).

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! OK - a couple of other things. I believe this piece was on the cover of a book of horror art (I saw that at a book fair). The book I saw this piece in had other art by the same artist - different themes but all horror and supernatural. I can' think of another one, but I remember the art was in a very distinctive style. The scene described was in daytime. It was NOT comic-book style. If I think of something else I'll comment. Note, I said I saw it in the 1970's, but could easily be from the 1960's. The style makes me think it could not have been much older than that.

Comment: Great. Don'tr forget to [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/191050/edit) that into your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the piece I was looking for! Not only that, but I found the book it was from (and found the book where it was on the cover). The artist was Bernie Wrightson, who was a very famous artist of the horror and supernatural. The book it was from was called "Back for More". One of my favorite and memorable art books from my youth. Here is the piece I was trying to find, and even though I got some of the details wrong, I guess I was pretty close.I got the rolling hills wrong. [image: Bernie Wrightson].

Comment: Excellent! And good on your for following up with posting an answer and accepting it.